# Rotate a 3D object in UI layer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class rotateCube : MonoBehaviour

{
  void Update()
  {
     transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0f, 10f*Time.deltaTime, 0f),Space.Self);
  }
}
```

Hi everyone(:(:
This simple code works fine ìf i associate it with a normal 3d object (just a normal cube) in default layer and not linked to a canvas. It doesn t work when the object is set to UI layer and linked to a canvas. I don t know how to write the proper code in this case. This thing is for animating the character in the character selection manu.
Thanks!!

I tried various other solutions that i found on the internet but they werent the case

Comment: why should it not work? what happens instead?

Comment: nothing happens, the cube just doesn t rotate

Comment: tested this and works for me ... are you sure nothing else is overruling the rotation maybe?

Comment: I don t think so, because when i add the script to the cube in default layer it works, when i i add it to the cube in UI layer it doesn t

Comment: It works for me too, the code is okay, make sure you attached the script to the correct object and there are no other components that override the rotation @oliveroliver

Comment: Ok! thank you all very much for the help!!!

Comment: also make sure your cube is not static

Comment: I did a silly omission that why it wasn working. Thanks al lot for the help otherewise i wouldn t have realized it!